# Best practice when asserting non-null on a value coming from React.useContext (or anywhere else really)

Tags: reactjs, typescript, react-hooks

In my React application I'm using the non-null assertion (!) to tell TS that the value coming from `useContext` hook is not null. It works well and seems to be the textbook use-case for non-null assertion, but with the recommended eslint rules **non-null assertion is a warning**.

Being new to TypeScript I want to make sure that I'm not missing a common pattern or best practice approach when dealing with these situations. Or maybe there is a different way to type the `user` object in the example below.

1. State is defined in a standalone file.

```
// context.ts
interface State {
  user: User | null; // User type is defined elsewhere, has 'id' and 'email'
}

const state: State = {
  user: null,
};
```

2. If user is logged in `state.user` in defined.

```
// App.tsx
return state.user ? <Dashboard /> : <Login />;
```

3. User can only see the Dashboard if `state.user` is not null, but I still see the following errors.

```
// Dashboard.tsx
const { state } = React.useContext(context);

const name = state.user.firstName; // Object is possibly 'null'.
const { id, email } = state.user; // Property 'id/email' does not exist on type 'User | null'.
```

4. Logout method sets `state = { user: null }` so null has to be assignable to the `User` type.

Anticipating potential answers that don't address my question about best practice/patterns:

- I know how to disable `@typescript-eslint/no-non-null-assertion` rule, this isn't the solution I'm looking for.
- I am aware that I can avoid both the errors and the non-null assertion warning if I use optional chaining in the first example like so: `const name = state.user?.firstName;`, but this doesn't answer my question. I'd actually prefer non-null assertion in this case, because would be more explicit.

Thanks!

Answer (score 8, accepted):

A couple of options for you:

1. Explicitly check that `user` isn't `null` and throw if it is
2. Define a "logged-in" state interface and write a hook that returns it after checking that `user` isn't `null`
3. Define a "logged-in" state interface and write a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions), then use that in `Dashboard` or the hook

The common theme among them is not just asserting that `user` isn't `null`, but proving it at runtime so programming errors using `state` with `null` are caught proactively and clearly, rather than being random-seeming "Can't use X of `null`" errors.

### 1. Explicit check

Since the user can only see the `Dashboard` component if they're signed in, and when they're signed in the `user` context member won't be `null`, you can check that explicitly:

```typescript
const { state } = React.useContext(context);
const { user } = state;
if (!user) {
    throw new Error(`ERROR: User reached Dashboard with null 'user' in context`);
}
// ...code uses `user`...
```

That way, TypeScript knows for the rest of the component code that `user` is not `null`, and you get a clear error if a programming error results in trying to use `Dashboard` when `user` is `null`.

### 2. LoggedInState and a hook

Alternatively, you could define `LoggedInState`:

```typescript
interface LoggedInState {
    user: User;
}
```

and write a reusable hook:

```typescript
function useLoggedInContext(context: ContextType): LoggedInState {
    const { state } = React.useContext(context);
    if (!state.user) {
        throw new Error(`ERROR: User reached logged-in-only component with null 'user' in context`);
    }
    return state as LoggedInState;
}
```

That still has a type assertion, but in a single reusable location with runtime code above proving that it's a correct assertion.

Then in `Dashboard` (and elsewhere):

```typescript
const { state } = useLoggedIncontext(context);
// ...
```

### 3. A type assertion function

You can wrap that up in a [type assertion function](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/release-notes/typescript-3-7.html#assertion-functions):

```typescript
function assertIsLoggedInState(state: State): asserts state is LoggedInState {
    if (!state.user) {
        throw new AssertionError(`'state' has a null 'user' member, expected a logged-in state`);
    }
}
```

Then either use it directly in `Dashboard`:

```typescript
const { state } = React.useContext(context);
assertIsLoggedInState(state);
// ...code can use `state.user`, which TypeScript now knows can't be `null`
```

or use it in that `useLoggedInContext` hook:

```typescript
function useLoggedInContext(context: ContextType): LoggedInState {
    const { state } = React.useContext(context);
    assertIsLoggedInState(state);
    return state; // TypeScript knows this is a LoggedInState
}
```

---

As a minor tweak to the first one: If you don't need `state` for anything else, you can combine those first two statements:

```typescript
const { state: { user } } = React.useContext(context);
// ...
```

That only declares `user`, without declaring `state`. If you have other things from `state` that you need, you could add them after `user`.

Comment: This is a very in-depth answer with some great advice. Thanks for that! My reasoning for asserting rather than proving was that there __is__ an if-statement already (in App.tsx), TS just doesn't know about it. But I guess there's nothing stopping someone misusing the Dashboard component outside of this if-statement. In this case including the check into the component itself makes a lot more sense. Thanks again.